# How to force key frames at given interval using ffmpeg with h.264_qsv?

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264

I use the following command to force key frames every 5th second and set minimum key frame interval in ffmpeg.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 24 profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -x264opts keyint=$keyFrameInterval:min-keyint=$keyFrameInterval:no-scenecut:pass=1 -movflags +faststart -strict -2 -acodec aac -y output.mp4
```

This seems to work well with **libx264**.
Now i am using the following command with **h264_qsv**. But i could only force key frames every 5th second and couldn't set minimum key frame interval.

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel qsv -i input.mp4 -vcodec h264_qsv -pix_fmt nv12 -preset:v faster -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*5)" -movflags +faststart -strict -2 -acodec aac -f mp4 -r 24 -y output.mp4
```

How do i achieve the above with h264_qsv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite a bit of study, I found that setting (group of pictures) -g frameRate*segmentDuration to the key frame interval solved my issue.